# php pass and get parameter

Tags: php, parameter-passing

```
<?php $daerah_ejen1 = "$_GET[daerah_ejen]";
$kumpulan_ejen1 ="$_GET[kumpulan_ejen]";

echo $daerah_ejen1;
echo $kumpulan_ejen1;
echo $kumpulan_ejen;

$sql= "SELECT * FROM data_ejen WHERE daerah_ejen= '$daerah_ejen1' AND kumpulan_ejen='Ketua Kampung' ORDER BY nama_ejen";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or @error_die("Query failed : $sql " . mysql_error());
?>
```

my url

```
laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen=HULU+LANGAT&kumpulan_ejen=Ketua Kampung
```

for output `daerah_ejen` variable has display,
but for `kumpulan_ejen`/`kumpulan_ejen1` is not display.

i dont know where the problem

Comment: You are **`echo $kumpulan_ejen;`** but you don't seem to have set **`$kumpulan_ejen`** anywhere. You've only set **`$kumpulan_ejen1`**

Answer (score 3):

your quotes accessing  $_GET variable is invalid. try this

```
<?php 
  $daerah_ejen1 = $_GET["daerah_ejen"];
  $kumpulan_ejen1 =$_GET["kumpulan_ejen"];
```

and you should read something about security, because you can pass malicous code to your script!

edit:// you can have a look on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539692/sanitizing-user-input-php

Comment: the first part of your answer is wrong. you can access the way the OP used.

Comment: but than, the 'daerah_ejen' for example will be treated as an constant, and since its not defined, its cast to a string. this is quite bad practise and raise notices within your application. so its just a lucky incident, that this actually works!

Comment: can you tell me what kind notice you was talking about ?

Comment: If your error_reporting and display_error php setting is switched on, you may see notice such as this: "Notice: Use of undefined constant daerah_ejen - assumed 'daerah_ejen'.

Answer (score 3):

you are converting get values in string using double quotes so remove and try

```
$daerah_ejen1 = $_GET['daerah_ejen'];
$kumpulan_ejen1 =$_GET['kumpulan_ejen'];
```

also use [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put the `$_GET['name']` in double quotes, wrap it in `{}` brackets.

e.g.

```
$kumpulan_ejen1 ="{$_GET['kumpulan_ejen']}";
```

Also, as  dbh pointed out, you only have `$kumpulan_ejen1`, not `kumpulan_ejen`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The quotes go around the parameter name. This is because `$_GET[]` is an associative array and its values are referenced using a string key

   `$daerah_ejen1 = $_GET['daerah_ejen'];`

   `$kumpulan_ejen1 =$_GET['kumpulan_ejen'];`
2. Always sanitize your parameter values before using them in a query to protect yourself against SQL injection.

   `$daerah_ejen1 = mysqli::real_escape_string($daerah_ejen1)`

Answer (score 0):

You face 2 problem on your code :

1st is :

```
$daerah_ejen1 = "$_GET[daerah_ejen]";
$kumpulan_ejen1 ="$_GET[kumpulan_ejen]";
```

replace it by this :

```
 $daerah_ejen1 = $_REQUEST['daerah_ejen'];
$kumpulan_ejen1 =$_REQUEST['kumpulan_ejen'];
```

2nd is :

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM data_ejen WHERE daerah_ejen= '$daerah_ejen1' AND kumpulan_ejen='Ketua Kampung' ORDER BY nama_ejen";
```

replace it by this :

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM data_ejen WHERE daerah_ejen= '".$daerah_ejen1. "' AND kumpulan_ejen='Ketua Kampung' ORDER BY nama_ejen";
```

Comment: can you tell me why you advice the OP to replace the `$_GET` to the way you have used ?

Comment: The second problem is not a problem. You can write `"'$variable'"` inside double quotes and get the desired result.

Comment: $_REQUEST represent $_GET and $_POST. I used $_REQUEST is easier your code which no need care about which $_GET or $_POST should use.

Comment: the question was asked before you change `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST`. And as said by W.K.S the second problem you mentioned was not a problem.Also changing to `$_REQUEST` will no way solve the problem

Comment: i recommend 2nd problem it more safety for your code.

Comment: @user3454436 safety by what means ?

Comment: for me it can make it clear for my code. I just recommend it. if i get any wrong i thanks for correct me.